# How to access to bottom view swift

Tags: ios, swift

[image: Storyboard screenshot]

I have two UIViewController. `NewBuyViewController` and `NewTransformViewController`. Now, I need to use some data from `NewTransformViewController` in `NewBuyViewController`. I've used this code in `NewBuyViewController`:

```
let presentingView1 = self.presentingViewController as! UINavigationController
let presentingView2 = presentingView1.presentingViewController as! NewTransferViewController
```

but it crashes in second line. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please always include the error message / console messages you receive.

You are getting an error because `presentingViewController` returns the currently presented modal viewController, on top of the viewController in question.

`presentingView1` is a `UINavigationController` that doesn't have a modal viewController. It has a `rootViewController`, and possibly later on a collection of `viewControllers`.

The crash is because you are force casting ( `as!` ) the second `presentingViewController`, which is returning nil, because it doesn't exist. Any attempt to force cast a nil will crash. You should avoid force casting at all costs unless absolutely necessary.

Instead try accessing the rootViewController like so:

```
if let secondViewController = presentingView1.rootViewController as? NewTransferViewController {
    // Do something with `secondViewController`
}
```